# Delete an entire Excel row if condition in one cell is met?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Just to say, I can't use VBA code. It has to be all built into excel. Let's say that I have 5 columns. In column 2 if the value there is 0 then it should delete/clear the remaining 4 columns. Is this possible?

Comment: if it is a requirement to not use VBA, then there are limited options, expecially if the cells you wnat to do this to are values and not formulas. See my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up an equal number of columns to the right of the columns, let's say A to E.

1. You could have a formula set up like this: `=IF($B1=0,0,A1)` Then, you could drag the columns to the right and down.

[image]